# Specific Page Link Hover

Tags: css, hover, hyperlink

I am having problems making just the three links on the bottom of my page change color when hovered. View Current Jobs » Get Started Now » and View Community Profiles » are the links i would like to work on. Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks for the help.

http://www.jobspark.ca/

Comment: You have rules like `a:link, a:visited, a:active{font-weight: -; font-style: -; text-decoration: none; color: #FF9900;}`. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to remove the inline style rules that are wrapping around them, otherwise they'll override anything you write in a `.css` file.

Then you could add a class to each of these anchors, let's say `.call-to-action`.

```
<a href="/job-listings/" class="call-to-action">View Current Jobs »</a>
<a href="/post-a-job/" class="call-to-action">Get Started Now »</a>
<a href="/community-profiles/" class="call-to-action">View Community Profiles »</a>
```

Then you can style it like so:

```
.call-to-action { color: orange; }
```

Comment: Thanks so I am pretty sure I removed all the inline style. Can you take a look and see what else I need. I put in the CSS and didnt quite work  .call-to-action a:hover {
color: #B50938 !important;
}

Comment: Your issue here is that you're trying to target an anchor within the class selector. The anchor however is the item referenced by the class. So instead you want: `.call-to-action:hover { color: #B50938; }` or you can have the anchor element there like this: `a.call-to-action:hover { color: #B50938; }` but it's not required.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added this to my notes to I can use it as a reference.